# Событие на закрытие окна на js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно повесить функцию на закрытие вкладки/окна. Т.е юзеру перед закрытием вкладки выскакивает попап окно и не закрывается вкладка. При закрытии попап окна - закрывается вкладка. Я попробовал реализовать через beforeunload, но проблема в том, что при закрытии выскакивает модальное окно с вопросом: 
 *"Эта страница просит вас подтвердить, что вы хотите уйти — при этом введённые вами данные могут не сохраниться."*

Возможно ли обойти это сообщение? Стоит его обходить? Можно как-то по-другому реализовать?

Как реализовано сейчас:

```
$(window).one("beforeunload", function() {
  openPopup(1000);
  return "Вы не зарегистрированы!";
});
```

Функция openPopup открывает окно magnificPopup.

```
function openPopup(time){
  var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!mfp.isOpen) {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
        src: $(".callback")
      },
      type: "inline"
    });
            }
  }, time);
}
```

Comment: Обойти это сообщение нельзя. Если, конечно,  у вас не IE 6))

Comment: Ничего с этим не сделать. Из-за негодяев, блокирующих закрытие вкладок, эту защиту с делали.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. А есть аналог beforeunload?